# The browser isn't being correctly identified and problems with Whatsapp Web

Tags: firefox, whatsapp

Today I was trying to access WhatsApp Web in Firefox and then, this screen was displayed, with no messages, nor a QR code to scan:

[image: WhatsApp Web screenshot]

It sounded strange, because I never had this issue. Then, I accessed some sites that identify the browser. Some said I'm using Chrome 53, and one was unable to identify my browser.

[image: whatsmybrowser.org screenshot]

I'm 70% sure that I can't access WhatsApp Web due to this browser detecting issue. Is there something I can do about this? I'm using the **most recent Firefox version provided by the Ubuntu software** and **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Comment: It works in mine.

Comment: You may be using some addon that changes the user agent or something.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Isn't this more likely to be a certificate problem?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04:

- Removing *web.whatsapp.com Data* under **Preferences > Advanced > Network > Offline Web Content and User Data**

What did not work:

- Removing WhatsApp cookies
- Updating certificates as [suggested by Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/a/890543/527764)

Answer (score 0):

I thought at first it might have something to do with running a private session, but testing indicates this is not the case. Since your accessing the site via https (Secure Hyper Text Transport Protocol) Updating your certificates with `sudo update-ca-certificates` should do the trick.